# Unable to set Single Array list data in two different spinner android

Tags: android, spinner

I Have a plans listing array like (A,B,C,D,E,F) and two spinner Plan1 and Plan2 i redirect from another screen where i select two plan and compare plans with the help of spinner but problem is if i select plan A and plan B in plan A drop down plan B is not listed and In plan B plan A is not listed how to that .

Comment: post your code so that I can help .

Comment: You must notify adapter that data inside has been changed. Eveny time, when you are changing spinner source, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter.